# How to get account created in by customer id in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

[image]

$customerID = $object->getCustomerId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerID);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the load, use the customer repository instead:

```
  $customerRepo = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
$customer = $customerRepo->getById(1);
```

You should be able to do

```
$customer->getCreatedIn();
```

Or, if it is a custom attribute, just look in the custom_attributes, like this:

```
$customer->getCustomAttribute('created_in')->getValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats your purpose in getting the Customer object, if in a module, in Magento 2 there are different ways to get the customer object, like by injecting the customer repository?

If you are creating a custom API, there is a different way to get the customer Object like through an access token.

But you should not Object Manager to get the Customer Object, you can use The Magento dependency injection mechanism enables you to override the functionality of the Magento_Customer module.

Api repository

```
protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;
public function __construct(
 ....
 \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
 ....
) {
 ....
 $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
}
```

Call the function:

```
$customerId = 1;
$customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
```